# selector in SCSS not getting property value

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am trying to **change** **value of font-size** for class **.cart__icon** (fa fa-shopping-cart) in my Header.module.scss file. I was even trying to test if !important set will change something but its not.
App.js file:

```
 import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
 import "./App.css";

 function App() {
 return (
 <div>
  <Header />
 </div>
);
}
```

export default App;

Header.jsx file:

```
import styles from "./Header.module.scss";
const Header = () => {
return (
<header className={styles.header}>
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.header__wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.logo}>
        <h1 className={styles.logo__title}>
          <span>Mamma</span>Mia!
        </h1>
        <h2 className={styles.logo__subtitle}>
          the best homemade italian food
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.cart}>
        <div className={styles.cart__summary}>
          <span className={styles.cart__total_number}>0</span>
          <span className={styles.cart__total_price}>
            Total price: <strong>$0</strong>
          </span>
          <i className="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart cart__icon"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
);
};

 export default Header;
```

Sass:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
 padding: (12px * 5) 0;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
 
 &__wrapper {
 position: relative;
 }
.container {
 max-width: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
}

.logo {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 1;

 &__title {
 margin: 0 0 12px 0;
 font-size: (12px * 4);
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;

 span {
 font-weight: 700;
 }
 }

 &__subtitle {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: (12px * 1.5);
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: italic;
 }
 }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////
 .cart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  right: 0;
  top: 12px;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ff6b6b;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 9999;

  &.active {
 .cart__content {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  max-height: 1000px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: (12px * 1.5) 0 0 0;
  }
  }

  &__summary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

  &__icon {
  font-size: 24px !important;
  }

  &__total_number {
  background: #ff6b6b;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  }

  &__total_price {
  color: #333;
  }

  &__content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: flipdown 0.5s ease both;
  color: #333;
  }

  &__order_summary {
  li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .widget_amount {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;

  input {
    margin: 0;
    width: (12px * 2);
    height: (12px * 2);
  }

  &:hover .btn-quantity--lt {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  }
  }

  &__product_name {
  width: 150px;
  }

  &__action_buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 0;

  i {
  font-size: 14px;
  }

  li {
  margin: 0 0 0 12px;
  }

  a {
  color: #ff6b6b;

  &:hover {
    color: lighten(#ff6b6b, 3%);
  }
  }
  }

  &__order_price {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 1px solid lighten(#333, 70%);

  li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
  }

  &__order_confirmation {
  border-top: 1px solid lighten(#333, 70%);
  padding: 12px 0 0 0;

  input,
  button {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: (12px * 0.5);
  }
  }
  }
```

font-size of this element is inherited but i can not find the answer how to change this property value is sass.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer for question of mine:
instead of this:

```
 <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart cart__icon"></i>
```

I used it:

```
 <i className={"fa fa-shopping-cart" + " " + styles.cart__icon}></i>
```

if some1 can find another solution i will be gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came across a similar problem long time ago. In my case, the `fa` class was overriding the remaining two classes. So I did something like:

```css
.fa {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the `height` and `width` of the icon instead of `font-size`. I think you should look into the browser DevTools/Elements tab to investigate what the problem is. See what class and property is being applied.